# Import registry keys from backed up version

Tags: windows-registry, import

I have backed up my full registry (local machine, current user,..).  Now I want to recover around 10 or 15 keys from the current user branch, I don't want to import the entire registry. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The settings for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU)` are stored in `NTUSER.dat`, which is found under the `%USERPROFILE%` directory, usually, `C:\users\username\ntuser.dat`, where *username* is the relevant account name. When a user logs into the system, its contents are merged into the registry.

If you have a backup of that file, you can recover registry keys from it using the free command line utility [RegFileExport](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_file_offline_export.html) from Nirsoft to [read the file and export keys](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/registry/recover_hkcu.php) to a file you specify.

Or you can use it to read some other registry file you have and extract only a portion of that file. E.g.:

```
regfileexport "c:\users\jdoe\ntuser.dat" "desktop_reg.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"
```

The first parameter is the file you wish to use for input, the second parameter is the output file you wish to be created and the third is the portion of the registry file you wish saved in the output file (everything within it will be saved in the output file).

Answer (score 0):

How did you back it up? If you used the built in backup and backed them up in .reg files, it would be fairly quick to just open the .reg file in a text editor, and search to find each key, and copy that into another file. Copy the header from the .reg file as well. Then save the new text file as another .reg file, and import it into the registry.

The file is laid out in a hierarchical manner, so if your keys are all in one place, they should be easy to find. It would almost be like "exploring" the .reg file.